# Como emitir som (beep)? - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

Preciso emitir som (beep) no Smartphone para chamar a atenção do usuário, estou testando apenas por um botão inicialmente. Os códigos que tenho testado só dá erro, o último está sendo do link [aqui](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/). O que fiz do que entendi está abaixo:

```
   //Botão Som
        private void Som_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            player.Load("Glass_audio.mp3");

            player.Play();
            Task.Delay(10000);
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A mensagem parece-me bem clara: a operação não é suportada pela plataforma. Onde está executando isso? Ela deveria suportar?

Comment: Desculpe, eu não tinha especificado bem. Leia a descrição agora que dá pra entender melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função beep não é compativel com plataforma Android.

Para correres um som de aviso em Android [segue este guia.](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/)

Comment: Desculpe, eu não tinha especificado bem, agora modifiquei a pergunta.

Comment: O comando beep não é compatível com aparelhos Android, se tiver a correr isso num Android vai dar esse erro porque não é suportado nessa plataforma.

Comment: Adicionem um guia que podes seguir para adicionar uma biblioteca de sons para uso em Android

Comment: Parece realmente que será por esse link a resposta que preciso, só não estou conseguindo finalizar o teste de vez, modifiquei a pergunta novamente por conta dos avanços no teste, se puder ajudar em algo fico grato.

Comment: Só pra deixar claro, na primeira imagem ao clicar dentro da pasta `Assets` -> `Glass_audio.mp3` -> `Ação de Compilação` -> Não escolher o `Recurso Inserido` (como está na imagem), mas `AndroidAsset`. Não funcionará pelo Genymotion, apenas pelo aparelho físico.

Comment: Que opções tens na "Ação de Compilação"?

Comment: E verifica que estás a inserir o nome correctamente. "Glass_audio.mp3" é case sensitive por isso vê as maiúsculas também.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80620/discussion-between-deivid-souza-and-pbras).

Answer (score 0):

No namespace System.Media tem uma classe chamada SystemSounds, que contém métodos para executar os principais sons associados no Windows (Beep, Asterisk, Question, Exclamation e Hand).

Assim, basta utilizar essa classe para tocar o som que você deseja.

```
using System.Media;

public class MinhaClasse
{
public void TocarBeep()
{
    // Toca o som associado ao Beep, no Windows
    SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
}
}
```

Podendo haver erro ocasionado pela versão do SO utilizado. Nesse caso deve ser usado algo mais específico.

Comment: Desculpe, eu não tinha especificado bem, agora modifiquei a pergunta.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada, voce vai encontrar a resposta aqui - http://www.macoratti.net/16/07/xamand_som1.htm

Comment: Nesse link é explicado mais sobre Xamarin Android, preciso que seja Xamarin Forms. Estou com esse link e testando: https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta para atualizar os testes que tenho feito, se puder ajudar em algo agradeço.

Comment: Eu trabalho com desktop, porém esse tipo de erro de not found quando é inserido um arquivo é resolvido copiando para a pasta de debug, mantendo a mesma estrutura de pastas. No caso copiar o arquivo de som para dentro da pasta "Assets" que está na pasta debug. Também pode testar selecionar "Copiar sempre" ao invez de "Nao copiar" nas propriedades do arquivo mp3.

Comment: Agradeço, deu certo acompanhando o link que deixei na pergunta.